# Laravel 5.3 pre-built authentication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement authentication for my application using pre-built authentication provide by Laravel . Used command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

The proplem is when i'm trying to login, i get "These credentials do not match our records." but the register work fine .

**Note**

The user table  DDL create syntax .

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PASSWORD CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  REMEMBER_TOKEN VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  ('ID')
);
```

Comment: Write DB column names in small letter.

Comment: I tried it , the error is disappeared. But I can't login it redirect me to login page without error . Other thing , this name of user before didn't appear now it appears .(I show it after registration)

Comment: Thank you @Ravi , it work . The other problem that i define the $primaryKey property value  in model Uppercase .

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your problem is resolved :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quoting answer provided as comment from Ravi Hirani

> Write DB column names in small letter. – Ravi Hirani